# Best place to discuss question relate to angularjs2.0 transition

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a discussion need to post about AngularJS 2.0 and people's opinion on js framework's future.

Where is the best place to post such discussion?

Thanks!

Comment: Chat.  Definitely not on any SE site.

Answer (score 4):

Such discussions would be off topic anywhere on the SE network.